# django inlineformset save new parent and child

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

The goal is to create a webpage that allows people to take pictures and submit meta data about the pictures. Because there can be multiple pictures for the same meta data I've setup the models like so:

#### models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class MetaData(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    metadata_id = models.ForeignKey(
        MetaData, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='image_to_metadata'
    )
```

With the models simple forms were created:

#### forms.py

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import MetaData, Image

class MetaDataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MetaData
        fields = '__all__'

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image',)

MetaDataImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MetaData, Image, fields=('image',), extra=1)
```

then using the following view to display them and authentication based on the following guide [Django inline formsets with class based views](https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6)

#### views.py

```py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.db import transaction

from .forms import MetaDataForm, MetaDataImageFormSet
from .models import MetaData

class CaptureView(CreateView):
    model = MetaData
    template_name = 'pages/capture.html'
    form_class = MetaDataForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(CaptureView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['images'] = MetaDataFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['images'] = MetaDataFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        images = context['images']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if images.is_valid():
                images.instance = self.object
                images.save()
        return super(CaptureView, self).form_valid(form)
```

#### urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", CaptureView.as_view(), name="capture"),
]
#  Hiding django toolbar paths and error page handling
```

When I try to post an image I get the following error message

> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
>     85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> The above exception (null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, test1).
>   ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py" in inner
>     74.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
>     172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
>     142.             return self.form_valid(form)
>
> File "C:\code\capture_version_2\receipts\views.py" in form_valid
>     27.             self.object = form.save()
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
>     458.             self.instance.save()
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
>     718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
>     748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
>     831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
>     869.                                using=using, raw=raw)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
>     82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
>     1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
>     1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py" in execute
>     186.         return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py" in _record
>     124.             return method(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
>     100.             return super().execute(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
>     68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
>     77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
>     85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in **exit**
>     89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>
> File "C:\Users\dbutler\capture_version_2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
>     85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> Exception Type: IntegrityError at /
>   Exception Value: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, test1).

Comment: by writing `class Image(forms.ModelForm)` you're redefining `Image` to be the form, not the model. This breaks everything following.

Comment: also your inline formset is for editing images, so passing `form=MetaDataForm` is wrong. You don't need to pass any form by default django auto-creates the form for the `Image` model with all fields you specify. You should just pass in `fields = ('image', )` that's enough.

Comment: Thank you @dirkgroten! I updated based on your comments. I still receive the same error. Essentially the image is not being saved to the database but no errors are shown which is really odd.On the webpage when I manually test it I'm adding the errors to the page and nothing is showing up.

Comment: Show us the full error trace and update your question with the code you are actually using now

Comment: @dirkgroten it is updated now. I was converting the more complex code to a simplified version for this question. I just created a test branch with the code above and ran it then updated it with the following error. Thank you for making me do what I knew I needed to do from the start but was being lazy.

Comment: Strange it's failing on `form.save()` which is your `MetaDataForm`. Try `fields = ['description']` instead of  `fields = '__all__'`

Comment: This has been such a headache. I deleted the database then migrated everything again. The error message went away but the image is not being saved in the database (no error messages though) I plan to dig into this again next week.